# SPFx breakpoints and debugging from Visual Studio Code instead from Chrome

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sharepoint, office365, visual-studio-code

I am trying to find a way to debug my local SPFx workbench from Visual Studio Code instead from Chrome, but I could not find any guides on how to attach the Chrome to Visual Studio Code and hit a breakpoint in my react typescript webpart (web app). Are there any good guides on how to do it?

This may be something trivial, but I am new to the react-gulp-vs code world and in the past, it was relatively easy to debug javascript with Visual Studio and IExplorer and I am wondering if easy setup exists with Visual Studio Code as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick update on this. @gruss is right about the Debugger for Chrome, but I wanted to go one step further and create a guide.

The official documents from the Office Dev team here:
https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/debug-in-vscode

I found very useful article here:
http://www.eliostruyf.com/how-to-debug-your-sharepoint-framework-web-part

I also created one here:
http://blog.velingeorgiev.pro/how-debug-sharepoint-framework-webpart-visual-studio-code

Gist with the launch.json config here:
https://gist.github.com/VelinGeorgiev/4a7b77ced7198df0a3898420d46f3405

The config pasted here for quick reference:

```
// Use Chrome browser to debug SharePoint Framework React webpart with Visual Studio Code on Windows
// - Install "Debugger for Chrome" extension
// - Add this configuration to the launch.json
// - Close all Chrome browser active instances
// - Start the SPFx nodejs server by executing "gulp serve"
// - Go to VS Code debug view (top menu -> View -> Debug)
// - Hit the play (start debugging) button
// Happy debugging!
// Full guides
// http://blog.velingeorgiev.pro/how-debug-sharepoint-framework-webpart-visual-studio-code
// https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/debug-in-vscode
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "SPFx Local",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench.html",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
                "webpack:///../../../src/*": "${webRoot}/src/*",
                "webpack:///../../../../src/*": "${webRoot}/src/*",
                "webpack:///../../../../../src/*": "${webRoot}/src/*"
            },
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--remote-debugging-port=9222"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "SPFx Online",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "https://<your_tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<your_site>/SitePages/<your_webpart_page>.aspx",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
                "webpack:///../../../src/*": "${webRoot}/src/*",
                "webpack:///../../../../src/*": "${webRoot}/src/*",
                "webpack:///../../../../../src/*": "${webRoot}/src/*"
            },
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--remote-debugging-port=9222"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "SPFx Online Workbench",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "https://<your_tenant>.sharepoint.com/_layouts/workbench.aspx",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
                "webpack:///../../../src/*": "${webRoot}/src/*",
                "webpack:///../../../../src/*": "${webRoot}/src/*",
                "webpack:///../../../../../src/*": "${webRoot}/src/*"
            },
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--remote-debugging-port=9222"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Please let me know if any issues.

Answer (score 1):

This VS Code extension might be what you need.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome